# How to return name,value pair via Java Map in Hibernate (using mapping file)

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to create a name,value pair in Hibernate which gets returned as a Java Map.  But I am only getting 1 of the rows returned in the Map.  I haven't found any really clear examples of a simple Map such as this and I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Due to a constrained environment, I am unable to run hbm2dll to generate the table, so I generated it by hand and it is possible that I have errors there.

Here are my parent and child tables:

```
mysql> select * from zoomProperties;
+----+---------------+
| id | entityVersion |
+----+---------------+
|  1 |             0 | 
+----+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from zoomProperty;
+----+-------+-------+----------------------+
| id | name  | value | parentZoomProperties |
+----+-------+-------+----------------------+
|  1 | prop1 | val1  |                    1 | 
|  2 | prop2 | val2  |                    1 | 
|  3 | prop3 | val3  |                    1 | 
+----+-------+-------+----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I only get one value back:

```
2010-12-28 16:45:58,437 ERROR [STDERR] setProperties with:
2010-12-28 16:45:58,453 ERROR [STDERR]  Key: prop1
2010-12-28 16:45:58,453 DEBUG [com.mycompany.zoom] Query returns 1 ZoomProperties
2010-12-28 16:45:58,453 ERROR [STDERR] getProperties returning:
2010-12-28 16:45:58,454 ERROR [STDERR]  Key: prop1
2010-12-28 16:45:58,454 DEBUG [com.mycompany.zoom] Key: prop1, Value: val1
2010-12-28 16:45:58,454 DEBUG [com.mycompany.zoom] ZoomProperies returned 1 properties
```

Here is my Hibernate query:

```
List resultList = em.createQuery("from ZoomProperties").getResultList();
log.debug("Query returns " + resultList.size() + " ZoomProperties");
```

Here is my mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.mycompany.zoom.domain.ZoomProperties" table="zoomProperties">
    <id name="id">
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <version name="entityVersion"/>

    <map name="properties" table="zoomProperty">
      <key column="id"/>
      <map-key column="name" type="string"/>
      <element column="value" type="string"/>
    </map>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And my pojo:

```
package com.mycompany.zoom.domain;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ZoomProperties
{
    private Long id;
    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Integer entityVersion;

    public ZoomProperties() {}

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    public Map<String, String> getProperties() //{ return properties; }
    {
        System.err.println("getProperties returning:");
        java.util.Set<String> propertyKeySet = properties.keySet();
        for (String key : propertyKeySet)
        {
            System.err.println("\tKey: " + key);
        }
        return properties;
    }
    public void setProperties(Map<String, String> properties) //{ this.properties = properties; }
    {
        this.properties = properties;
        System.err.println("setProperties with:");
        java.util.Set<String> propertyKeySet = properties.keySet();
        for (String key : propertyKeySet)
        {
            System.err.println("\tKey: " + key);
        }
    }

    public Integer getEntityVersion() { return entityVersion; }
    public void setEntityVersion(Integer entityVersion) { this.entityVersion = entityVersion; }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (other instanceof ZoomProperties)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return "This is the one and only ZoomProperties".hashCode();
    }
}
```

And my table creation info:

```
mysql> show create table zoomProperties;
+----------------+---------------------------------+
| Table          | Create Table                    |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| zoomProperties | CREATE TABLE `zoomProperties` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `entityVersion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1             | 
+----------------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table zoomProperty;
+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| Table        | Create Table                      |
+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| zoomProperty | CREATE TABLE `zoomProperty` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `parentZoomProperties` bigint(20) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `parentZoomProperties` (`parentZoomProperties`),
  CONSTRAINT `zoomProperty_ibfk_1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`parentZoomProperties`) 
    REFERENCES `zoomProperties` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1             | 
+--------------+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<key>` element inside `<map>` refers to the foreign key, so it should be

```
<map name="properties" table="zoomProperty">
    <key column="parentZoomProperties"/>
    <map-key column="name" type="string"/>
    <element column="value" type="string"/>
</map>
```

`id` in `zoomProperty` table is not needed at all.

Comment: Yes, indeed - that was the piece of information I needed!  Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!